# How do I calculate attack rolls for creatures in WFRP 4e

Tags: attack-roll, wfrp-4e

I've just begun running WFRP 4e and I don't get the weapon or bite traits in the bestiary. I understand that the rating (for example bite+9) is the damage including the strength bonus. But do you also add this number to the WS stat for attack tests? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You don't add the +9 to the WS for an attack test, no.

You *do* add the SL of the attack test to the +9 for damage, though.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).